# Why does the Server HTTP header exist?

Tags: http, http-headers

What is the Server HTTP response header useful for?  I have yet to actually see a use for it.  Why would someone that's requesting a webpage need to know what server a webpage is hosted on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has reminded me of the first HTTP server I wrote, which (obviously) returned the server header: `Why do you want to know?`

One possible answer to this question is "Because I'm doing a survey." For example, [this would be impossible](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/web_server_survey.html) without the Server header.

Answer (score 4):

*Server* doesn't mean the server that the resource is served from. [It's for advertising the implementation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38). As to its utility, that's a good question. Apache httpd can be configured not to include that header, since it can be considered a security issue.

Comment: That's not true: Apache does not allow to completely remove the Server-header. But it can be configured to be minimal and not expose the version. Too bad this advertisement cannot be removed. I had to patch it out in the executable!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. At one level, perhaps it was originally seen as a capability device, similar to the user-agent on the request (browscap etc). In reality, neither is really useful in this respect, and most code now uses other means to test for options. And in many ways the server is (indirectly) in control of the requests from well-behaved clients (if has an influencing factor, at least).

These days, it is sometimes seen as a security issue, and I know many places that block this header on html traffic. But for non-html (but still http) traffic (such as web-services) it may still serve a useful versioning purpose (although you often see a product-specific versioning header in such cases).

Answer (score 0):

The only purpose of the header seems to be security scanners and surveys how much market share each server has. In Apache it is not possible to completely remove the header, it can only be set to be minimal so that it just advertises "Apache". One needs to patch the binary to completely remove it or to recompile it oneself.

I think with IIS it is also not straight-forward to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Stats.. and whoever it was will give you idea when and how things are spreading..

Try the dons Google and see the 3 letter Server: response.. Plenty of those around since they purchased plenty of boxes years and years back.

[ It's like claiming that Apache or IIS was spreading too fast, right on my MP's expenses .. ]